# unable to locate elements in chrome page using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

this is the HTML code:

this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
timeout = 20
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://polarionprod1.delphiauto.net/polarion/#/project/10032024_MY21_FORD_PODS_SDPS_P702/wiki/10_Testing/SysTs_ATR')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
men_menu=0
while(men_menu==0):
    try:
        men_menu=WebDriverWait(driver, 
        timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#polarion_type_icon')))
        print(men_menu)
    except TimeoutException:
        if(men_menu==0):
            print(men_menu)
            continue
        else:
            men_menu.click()
            break
```

i have used try and except in loop since the web page I am dealing with takes a lot of time to load.When i run the code the code seems to be always in try block where I am printing the value men_menu to see if the element is located. But it always prints 0. So that's how i confirmed the element is not getting located

Comment: You didn't post the HTML

Comment: @sagar This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have posted the HTML code, i tired usual ways of locating and click the particular using below

Comment: HTML code:<img src="/polarion/icons/default/enums/type_test.gif" id="polarion_type_icon" style="cursor: pointer !important;" oncontrolselect="return false;">